# Pi Access Point - Hostname mapping

Tags: networking, wifi, php, access-point

I have my IP address mapped to a hostname "example.com" where I have a simple Welcome webpage. The webpage is written in PHP. After I successfully connect to the Pi Access Point I attempt to go to the hostname but it fails majority of the time. When I try the static IP it connects to the webpage right away. I have the Pi inside a plastic enclosure that is about 1/4 inch (6.35 mm) thick. What settings or possible issues could cause the hostname connection/IP translation to fail (or be severely delayed)?

Comment: Which IP is mapped to the domain name?  What is doing the DNS on the network?

Comment: Which `web server` do you use ? What is your content of `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: is it a Pi 4 and are you following the official documentation https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md ?